# Solving Recurrence relation by master method and its analysis

Tags: algorithm

what is the meaning of f(n) in the recurrence relation T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n),
and what is the meaning of f(n)=0(n^log(base b) a - e)for some e>0;
so just wanted to know the reason behind this log(base b)a.
i tried out with the recursion tree but got confused, so plz help me out.

Comment: If you want to understand this using a recursion tree, give `a`, `b` and `f(n)` some values. Example would be `a=2`, `b=2` and `f(n)=n`. But if you wanted to know why and how the master method works, then you should read the proof of it.

Answer (score 0):

f(n) means that there is a function f of a variable n, which represents the input size to some algorithm. T(n) gives the runtime of the algorithm for a given input size n. f(n) gives the non-recursive component of that runtime.

If f(n) = O(n^[log_b a-e]), then everything in square brackets is just some constant; this is equivalent to f(n) = O(n^k) for some constant k. Why they chose that constant is a question to ask them, but I suspect it was chosen because there's a comparison you have to do when using the Master Method and this is probably an instructive value: by carrying out the master method with this value, you will probably learn something about the Master Method and its application.

Comment: Thankss sir but have some confusion that what is the reason of taking that non-recursive component and how is it computed ,say in the case of binary search tree what will be f(n).i got the answer to be theta(1),but was just confused that we do the comparison of a number with the middle element so what is the reason behind taking it to be constant time when we have more than 1 middle elements from each sub-problem, which will be compared with the number to be searched.

Comment: @radhika It's O(1) for binary search because, for each call of the algorithm, the amount of non-recursive work is constant. True, in each recursive call, you do that same amount of work over and over again, but that's already taken into account by the Master Method. Think of the f(n) as the "glue"; recursive algorithms break problems into subproblems, solve those using the same method, then "glue" the pieces together to form the overall solution. f(n) represents the time it takes the "glue" to run on a given input size. The total runtime is the sum of total runtimes on subproblems,

Comment: plus "glue" at the local stage.

Comment: so then according to the recursion tree which we solve,we always consider that at the last stage the value decreases to order(1) the how come the value then changes to order(1) when we add up all the sub-problems computations,then for each problems we should have order(1),why do we get it differently as order(n^2) or order(n)

Comment: @radhika If you have additional questions, can you please add them, with examples, to your question? It's rather hard to follow the questions in the comments. Thanks for your understanding.